# Azure B2C - Pass Parameter via URL to ClaimType to Claim in Token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to pass a parameter via the request URL to B2C and then be able to send this out as a claim in the access token. I am guessing I will need to capture this in a claimType. How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can capture query string parameters using a `Claims Resolver`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2-key-value-parameters

For example, if you would like to capture the `?bandz=test` query string parameter, you could resolve that via the `{OAUTH-KV:bandz}` claims resolver.

In your `<RelyingParty>`'s output claims, you could then refer to a claim and the value like this:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="customClaimId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:bandz}" />
```

You would just need a Claim definition for `customClaimId`.